# Override runtime SLF4J binding for test

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I am writing a package. I need `slf4j-log4j12` with specific appender for runtime. But for tests, I just need a `slf4j-simple` binding. So, my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.bharani</groupId>
    <artifactId>LoggingDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Direct dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I run my program, I get **log4j** logs as expected. But when I run tests, I get:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/bharani/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/bharani/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.25/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

...and I don't see logs in Console as expected out of `slf4j-simple` binding.

How do I resolve this? How can keep `runtime` dependency on `slf4j-log4j12` away from tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a dependency of scope `runtime` is *also* included in the test classpath, so SLF4J ends up having two bindings and has to pick one of them (the binding it chooses is likely random, it happened that it picked log4j in your case).

A simple solution is to remove the log4j binding from the classpath of the Surefire plugin:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

More info in http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html.

Comment: Doing `mvn test` works but it still doesn't work when running tests using Intellij because of an open issue with Maven integration. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206253879-IDEA-not-honoring-maven-surefire-properties?page=1#community_comment_115000543170 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52286

Comment: I was able to use this solution (with appropriate name changes) to deal with `slf4j-test` being needed at test time and `slf4j-simple` at runtime